# Detecting A click on the Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In my code I have a 800*800 canvas. It has a grid on it, and I have found this function:

```
    function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    var x, y;

    canoffset = $(canvas).offset();
    x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + 
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft - Math.floor(canoffset.left);
    y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + 
    document.documentElement.scrollTop - Math.floor(canoffset.top) + 1;

    return [x,y];
}
```

But how/where would I call this to detect when my canvas has been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you able to add an event Listener?

```
document.querySelector("canvas").addEventListener("click", e => handle(e))
```

Where `handle` is your event handler.

Comment: Did this work? usually for me, adding event listeners to querySelector elements doesn't work, and I have to get the element node, just wondering.